# Check for doubles in results and then delete row in another table if there are none

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, postgresql-10

I want to create a complex query that does the following

get `laptop`, `service`, `technician` of table `lst` according to laptop equals X (number)

of those rows you get, remove the `laptop` (cannot actually delete, so make it `null`)

of the same rows,maybe some did not had a `technician`. So they are rows that now contain just a `service`, with no `laptop` and no `technician`

Tricky part: keep all the `service` of those rows. 
 
If they are not found anywhere else in the `lst` table, being paired with other `laptop` or `technician` then go to the `service` table and delete that row. Then go back to the `lst` and delete all the rows that have that `service` and no `laptop` or `technician` .
If they are found anywhere else in the `lst` table, paired with other `laptop` or `technician` then just delete all the `lst` rows in the `lst` that have that `service` and no `laptop` or `technician`

Example

```
lst table
laptop service technician 
17     10      25
17     10      26
17      4      null
17      2      null
125     2      null
```

and we execute the above by having `laptop = 17`

becomes

```
laptop service technician 
null     10      25
null     10      26
null      4      null
null      2      null
125       2      null
```

Row number 3 has to be deleted because it has no `technician`  and no `laptop`. Also, the `service` 4 of the table `service` has to be deleted, since there is nowhere else to be found in the `lts` table , paired with anything.

Row number 4 has to be deleted because it has no `technician`  and no `laptop`. But the `service` 2 of the table `service` will not be deleted, since it is found elsewhere in the `lts`, paired with another `laptop` (last row)

So, the `lts` now becomes

```
laptop service technician 
null     10      25
null     10      26
125       2      null
```

and I only delete `service` 4 of the `service` table

I have tried several queries/subqueries combinations, like

```
select id , technician from lts where  laptop= 17 and  technician in(
  select id   from 
  lts 
  where id in
    (select id from lts where technician is null and  laptop = 17) 
);
```

But nothing works and nothing can keep all the ids to go and delete from the `service` table, later on.

I guess I will have to use a `pl/pgsql` function or a transaction, but even with the transaction I dont know how to briefly save any ids for later deleting from the `service` table.

Any ideas how to do this? A strategy or a basic code?

I use postgresql 10

Thanks

Comment: Just to get this straight: You want to delete records in `lst` where `laptop = "X" AND technician IS NULL` You go through a lot of `IF` logic to just say that. Furthermore if any `service` in those deleted records is ONLY present in those deleted records and nowhere else in `lst` then you want those corresponding records deleted from the `services` table. Is that right? So it's just two steps. 1) Delete services `DELETE FROM services WHERE service IN (SELECT service FROM lst WHERE laptop=17 AND technician IS NULL)` 2) Delete from `lst`: `DELETE FROM lst WHERE laptop=17 AND technician IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) like this to kind of store intermediate results and do several update operations in one query.

The query looks like this (to demo the idea - non tested):

```
WITH potentially_orphan_services AS (
    SELECT service
    FROM lts
    WHERE laptop = X AND technician IS NULL
), deleted_services AS (
    DELETE FROM services
    WHERE service IN (
       SELECT service
       FROM potentially_orphan_services p
       WHERE NOT EXIST (
         SELECT 1
         FROM lts l
         WHERE laptop != X AND l.service = p.service
       )
), deleted_lts_without_technician AS (
   DELETE FROM lts
   WHERE laptop = X AND technician IS NULL
)
UPDATE lts
SET laptop = NULL
WHERE laptop = X AND technician IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I was able to make it work with minor changes. Amazing thinking. Thank you so much.